# Changing column width in a combobox associated with a dataset in .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, combobox, dataset, datasource

I have a ComboBox with its datasource being a dataset from a SQL Server database.

The width of its columns are relative to the width of the name of the columns. I would like to increase that width in order to see the content properly and not cuted.

Here is a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see the values in the second column do not appear completly.

Here is the method I use to load a ComboBox:

```
Public Sub CargarComboAlternativo(ByVal Combo As ComboBox, ByVal query As String)
    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=" & Servidor & ";Database=" & Bdatos & ";Trusted_Connection=Yes;UID=" & UID & ";"
    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()

    Try
        Using conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            Using command As New SqlCommand(query, conn)

                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text

                conn.Open()

                adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(command)
                dataSet.Clear()
                adapter.Fill(dataSet)

                Combo.DataSource = dataSet
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Any suggestions?

I don't mind at all a suggestion in C#, I won't have problems to translate it to vb.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about somehting like at the end:

```
Dim total As Integer = 0
Dim maxLen As Integer = 0
For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
  total = 0
  For Each Str As String In row.ItemArray
    total = Str.Length + total
  Next
  If maxLen < total Then maxLen = total
Next

Combo.Width = maxLen + 5
```

I know its brute force but you'll find the longest item and set the width to that.  the +5 is for padding you may need to change that.

Comment: Never mind this.  looking back at your example I can see that your combo box isn't containing just a list of strings.

Comment: I've updated the solution in an attempt to point you in the right direction.  I'm not sure if the conversions will workout correctly for the itemArray to string objects.  let me know if this helps.